# RemoteDataError with Pandas_datareader

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I am trying to run this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
df = web.DataReader('goog', 'yahoo')
```

But for some reason since yesterday i have been getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteDataError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-e481b4b62766> in <module>
----> 1 df = web.DataReader('goog', 'yahoo')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    197                 else:
    198                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 199             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    200 
    201         return cast(F, wrapper)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, api_key)
    374 
    375     if data_source == "yahoo":
--> 376         return YahooDailyReader(
    377             symbols=name,
    378             start=start,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py in read(self)
    251         # If a single symbol, (e.g., 'GOOG')
    252         if isinstance(self.symbols, (string_types, int)):
--> 253             df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
    254         # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
    255         elif isinstance(self.symbols, DataFrame):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py in _read_one_data(self, url, params)
    151         url = url.format(symbol)
    152 
--> 153         resp = self._get_response(url, params=params)
    154         ptrn = r"root\.App\.main = (.*?);\n}\(this\)\);"
    155         try:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py in _get_response(self, url, params, headers)
    179             msg += "\nResponse Text:\n{0}".format(last_response_text)
    180 
--> 181         raise RemoteDataError(msg)
    182 
    183     def _get_crumb(self, *args):

RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/goog/history?period1=1467757800&period2=1625524199&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history
Response Text:
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n  <html lang="en-us"><head>\n  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n      <meta charset="utf-8">\n      <title>Yahoo</title>\n      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimal-ui">\n      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">\n      <style>\n  html {\n      height: 100%;\n  }\n  body {\n      background: #fafafc url(https://s.yimg.com/nn/img/sad-panda-201402200631.png) 50% 50%;\n      background-size: cover;\n      height: 100%;\n      text-align: center;\n      font: 300 18px "helvetica neue", helvetica, verdana, tahoma, arial, sans-serif;\n  }\n  table {\n      height: 100%;\n      width: 100%;\n      table-layout: fixed;\n      border-collapse: collapse;\n      border-spacing: 0;\n      border: none;\n  }\n  h1 {\n      font-size: 42px;\n      font-weight: 400;\n      color: #400090;\n  }\n  p {\n      color: #1A1A1A;\n  }\n  #message-1 {\n      font-weight: bold;\n      margin: 0;\n  }\n  #message-2 {\n      display: inline-block;\n      *display: inline;\n      zoom: 1;\n      max-width: 17em;\n      _width: 17em;\n  }\n      </style>\n  <script>\n    document.write(\'<img src="//geo.yahoo.com/b?s=1197757129&t=\'+new Date().getTime()+\'&src=aws&err_url=\'+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+\'&err=%<pssc>&test=\'+encodeURIComponent(\'%<{Bucket}cqh[:200]>\')+\'" width="0px" height="0px"/>\');var beacon = new Image();beacon.src="//bcn.fp.yahoo.com/p?s=1197757129&t="+new Date().getTime()+"&src=aws&err_url="+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+"&err=%<pssc>&test="+encodeURIComponent(\'%<{Bucket}cqh[:200]>\');\n  </script>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n  <!-- status code : 404 -->\n  <!-- Not Found on Server -->\n  <table>\n  <tbody><tr>\n      <td>\n      <img src="https://s.yimg.com/rz/p/yahoo_frontpage_en-US_s_f_p_205x58_frontpage.png" alt="Yahoo Logo">\n      <h1 style="margin-top:20px;">Will be right back...</h1>\n      <p id="message-1">Thank you for your patience.</p>\n      <p id="message-2">Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.</p>\n      </td>\n  </tr>\n  </tbody></table>\n  </body></html>'
```

Is the problem on my end? I even tried to use VPN but to no avail. What can i do to resolve this?

Comment: I had the same problem. At some recent point pdr stopped working with Yahoo (again). AlphaVantage doesn't carry all the stocks that Yahoo does; googlefinance package only gets current quotes as far as I can tell, not time series; the yahoo-finance package doesn't work (or I failed to get it to work); Econdb sends back some kind of weirdly-formed dataframe (maybe this is fixable); and Quandl has a paywall on non-US stocks.

I've suggested a workaround [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68226884/how-to-fix-new-unable-to-read-url-error-in-python-for-yahoo-finance/68302814#68302814)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Yahoo has restricted access to programmatically call their APIs.

There are some workarounds for that suggested in the [Github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/868)