# pandas.datareader.fred.read() {RemoteDataError}Unable to read URL

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I use pandas.datareader to download FRED data. The code is quite simple and worked well. I updated pandas and pandas-datareader in the new version of my software and since then it doesn't work anymore.

```
import pandas_datareader
import pandas as pd

downloader = pandas_datareader.fred
df_idx = downloader.FredReader('USD1MTD156N', start='1986-01-02', end='2021-06-30').read()
```

There are similar answers (for Yahoo) to this problem (for example: [How to fix new unable to read URL error in python for yahoo finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68226884/how-to-fix-new-unable-to-read-url-error-in-python-for-yahoo-finance)). But I don't find them very clear and so I can't find a solution adapted to the FRED case. Of course I would like to keep up to date with pandas and pandas-datareader versions.

> error:
> RemoteDataError}Unable to read URL: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/fredgraph.csv?
> id=USD1MTD156N
> Response Text:

```
pandas version: 1.4.2
pandas-datareader: 0.10.0
```

Comment: what's the data you're looking to download exactly ? is it economical indicators or prices?

Comment: Actually both. Why? is there a difference in the way of downloading the data?

Comment: because i fond a way for the economic indicatos but not yet for the price , maybe because of the changes they're making in their site, example you can try : `pandas_datareader.DataReader('GDP', 'fred', start='1986-01-02', end='2021-06-30')`

Comment: Yes, you are right. when I replace 'USD1MTD156N' by 'GDP' it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe for your specifc data : '*ICE Benchmark Administration Limited (IBA), 1-Month London Interbank Offered Rate (LIBOR), based on U.S. Dollar [USD1MTD156N],*'

It's been removed from FRED :
check the link below , it has the data that are no longer available , https://news.research.stlouisfed.org/2022/01/ice-benchmark-administration-ltd-iba-data-to-be-removed-from-fred/

other than that you're good to go, you can use :

```
    pandas_datareader.DataReader('GDP', 'fred', start='1986-01-02', end='2021- 
    06-30')
```